# Plotting for Set of Initial Conditions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I have solved my system of coupled odes. I have solved it for a set of initial conditions which I had to provide manually, making complications for me. I know there would be an efficient method through which I can obtain a number of plots against a set of initial conditions.
Here is my attempt,

```
H = Sqrt[(1/
3)*(0.5/(a^6*V^2*Exp[6*t])*(P[t]^2 + 0.5*sig^2) + (0.25*m^2*
M^2)*(1 - Exp[-1/(sig^2*M^2)]*Cos[2*\[Psi][t]/M]) + (0.25*g*
M^3)*(Cos[3*\[Psi][t]/M]*Exp[-(9/4)*(sig^2*M^2)] + 
3*Sin[\[Psi][t]/M]*Exp[-0.25/(sig^2*M^2)]))];
```

My equations are:

```
eqs = {\[Psi]'[t] == P[t] Exp[-3 t]/(H a^3 V), 
P'[t] == -(a^3 *V *
Exp[3 t])*((0.5)* ( 
m^2 Exp[-1/(M^2*sig^2)] Sin[2 \[Psi][t]/M]) - (3*g*
M^2)*(Sin[3*\[Psi][t]/M]*Exp[-(9/4)*(sig^2*M^2)] + 
Cos[\[Psi][t]/M]*Exp[-0.25/(sig^2*M^2)]))};
```

Here is my solution code:

```
  sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eqs /. {M -> 1.0, m -> 1.0, V -> 1, a -> 1, 
  sig -> 1000.0, g -> 050}, \[Psi][-10] == c, 
  P[-10] == b}, {\[Psi], P}, {t, -10, 12}, {c, b}, 
  MaxSteps -> 100000];
```

Finally, here is my attempt with manually provided initial conditions:(That's pretty hard for me):

```
 plot = ParametricPlot3D[{{t, \[Psi][16, 12][t], 
 P[16, 12][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {t, \[Psi][14, 10][t], 
 P[14, 10][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {t, \[Psi][1, 3][t], 
 P[1, 3][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {t, \[Psi][4, 4][t], 
 P[4, 4][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {t, \[Psi][6, 2][t], 
 P[6, 2][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {t, \[Psi][10, 4][t], 
 P[10, 4][t]/Exp[3*t]}, t, \[Psi][12, 6][t], 
 P[12, 6][t]/Exp[3*t], {t, \[Psi][-1, -3][t], 
 P[-1, -3][t]/Exp[2.5*t]}, {t, \[Psi][-4, -4][t], 
 P[-4, -4][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {t, \[Psi][-6, -2][t], 
 P[-6, -2][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {t, \[Psi][-10, -4][t], 
 P[-10, -4][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {t, \[Psi][-12, -6][t], 
 P[-12, -6][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {t, \[Psi][-14, -10][t], 
 P[-14, -10][t]/Exp[3*t]}} /. sol, {t, -10, 12}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "\[Psi]", "P"}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

This is quite messy. I I want to create a set of initial conditions. For example, I want to give initial conditions; P[-10] ranging from (-5,5) and $\psi[-10]$=(-5,5), and for each value of P[-10] whole range of $\psi[-10]$ gets plotted.
Can we do something like that in Mathematica easily?
Please assist,
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
curves = Flatten[
   Table[{t, ψ[a, b][t], P[a, b][t]/Exp[3*t]}, {a, -5, 
      5}, {b, -5, 5}] /. sol, 1];
curves // Length;(*11*11= 121 curves *)
plot = ParametricPlot3D[curves // Evaluate, {t, -10, 12}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "ψ", "P"}, 
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Sir, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: One more thing, can you tell by how much difference our initial conditions are working?